# Creating a class from an XML file that can be enumerated through

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I tried to use xsd.exe to create a class for my xml and it seemed to work but I can enumerate though the class. I even tried to use Xsd2Code but that would cause this error "There was an error reflecting type 'MySQlXML.XBMC'." when I tried to 
enumerate through the list. Please let me know if you have any ideas how i could get the enumeration to work.

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XBMC>
  <Show>
    <IdShow>1</IdShow>
    <TheTvDbId>248741</TheTvDbId>
    <ShowName>2 Broke Girls</ShowName>
    <Seasons>
      <Season>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Path>\\10.0.0.3\tv\2 Broke Girls\Season1\</Path>
      </Season>
      <Season>
        <Number>3</Number>
        <Path>\\10.0.0.3\tv\2 Broke Girls\Season 03\</Path>
      </Season>
    </Seasons>
  </Show>
  <Show>
    <IdShow>164</IdShow>
    <TheTvDbId>75682</TheTvDbId>
    <ShowName>Bones</ShowName>
    <Seasons>
      <Season>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Path>\\10.0.0.3\TV2\Bones\Season 01\</Path>
      </Season>
    </Seasons>
  </Show>
</XBMC>
```

This is how serialize the data but when i try a  `foreach (XBMCShow show in test)` I get **foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'MySQlXML.XBMC' because 'MySQlXML.XBMC' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'**

```
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(_XMLFile);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XBMC));
    test = (XBMC)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
```

This is Class xsd.exe generated .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace MySQlXML
{  
    /// <remarks/>
    public partial class XBMC
    {

        private XBMCShow[] showField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Show")]
        public XBMCShow[] Show
        {
            get
            {
                return this.showField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.showField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>

    public partial class XBMCShow
    {

        public ushort idShowField;

        public string theTvDbIdField;

        public string showNameField;

        private XBMCShowSeason[] seasonsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort IdShow
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idShowField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idShowField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string TheTvDbId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.theTvDbIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.theTvDbIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ShowName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.showNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.showNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Season", IsNullable = false)]
        public XBMCShowSeason[] Seasons
        {
            get
            {
                return this.seasonsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.seasonsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>

    public partial class XBMCShowSeason
    {

        private byte numberField;

        private string pathField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte Number
        {
            get
            {
                return this.numberField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.numberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pathField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pathField = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
foreach (XBMCShow show in test.Show) {
                               ----
                                 ^

     if(show.ShowName == "Bones") {
         ...
```

you missed the dot-Show part

Comment: Ok that worked thanks, one last thing how would I select the "Bones" show from the array for example

Comment: Cool that would work what if I wanted to do the same thing with out looping though the entire array normally you can use the array index but this is not an  option hear want some thing like this `test.Show[].ShowName == "Bones"`

Comment: you can use LINQ. but to serach for an item in a collection you **will** need to iterate anyway. Either you do it in a for/while loop or let LINQ do that. somewhere or the other a loop will come.